# PHP [closures] [override method runtime] How Improve this wrapp

Tags: php, closures

I wrote this code for override a object method:

```
class A{
    public function foo(){
        echo "foo";
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo = function(){
    echo "don't work";
}
$a->foo();
```

but the above code doesn't work i tried use a Closure but it didn't work.

so i wrote  this utility class in my project, the class work and it works as expected.

```
class Wrapper
{
    public $wrapped;

    private $binds;
    private $obj;


    public function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->wrapped = true;
        $this->obj = $obj;
        $this->binds = [];
    }


    public function bind($name, $function){
        $this->binds[$name] = \Closure::bind($function, $this->obj, get_class($this->obj));
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->obj->$name = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $name)){
            return $this->$name;
        }
        return $this->obj->$name;
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->obj->$name);
    }

    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($this->obj->$name);
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {

        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->binds) ) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->binds[$name], $arguments);
        }
        return call_user_func_array([$this->obj, $name], $arguments);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([get_class($this->obj, $name), $name], $arguments);
    }
}
```

but the above class is a dirty fix, so how i can use the **closure** class or other method for do the same thing?

Comment: Why not just extend the class or make a decorator?

Comment: the core classes are very very very of large old php code over 2000 lines each class. so i don't want to create a new class for each core class (extends), the same happens with the decorators ( i don't want touch the core code ). so i only want to change the behavior in runtime when the class is needed.

Comment: Well, any solution that does not fix the underlying problem (the size of those "core" classes) is going to be a dirty fix, so I don't really think there's an answer available other than using something like a strangler pattern to try and salvage the situation. If it's simply a slightly cleaner dirty fix you're looking for, maybe [runkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) is something for you?

Comment: solve the "underlying problem" it will consume a lot of time. because the core code is new for me, ( and the things works :V ) so I could fix it in the right way, but i need a hot solution. this works, but is ugly i know. In python and javascript work with the first form ($this->url = function(){}) but in php not.

Comment: You cant just change the functionality of a PHP class method on the fly, it's not how inheritance works.  I can't speak for Python but JavaScript is a Prototype language and as such has  a completely different model for inheritance then PHP.